# SharePoint Online Communication Sites: tag news page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, managed-metadata

I have recently been playing around with the new communication sites in SPO. I would like to tag my news (which essentially are pages in the SitePages document library) with custom managed meta data terms.

So far I created a column in the document library, set its type to `Managed Metadata`, but the edit item form does not contain a field for this column.

This goes for adding the column using the modern UX as well as using classic UX. Any clues on that?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

If I created another content type inheriting from the website content type, would the communication site still accept it and display it as news element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested this on the new communication site and you will need to do the following:

1. Create a new content type (let's called it My Site Page) inheriting
   from Site Page content type
2. Create a Managed Metadata Site Column (e.g. Department)
3. Go to Pages Library Setting and add your content type
4. You can hide the existing Site Page content type

Here are some screenshots:

**Content Type**

[image]

**Managed Metadata Site Column**

[image]

**Edit Page Property**

[image]

Comment: This is what I suspected! But do those entries now show up in the news web part on the main page?

Comment: There is no support yet for this or at least I can't find any documentation.  This article talk about the web part but customization is very limited https://support.office.com/client/Use-the-News-web-part-on-a-SharePoint-page-c2dcee50-f5d7-434b-8cb9-a7feefd9f165.  As always MS will provide us half-baked stuff :)

Comment: Hi @bash.d Please don't forget to mark and upvote the correct answer as accepted in case it helped u , thanks

Comment: @M.Qassas You are right, so I did it!